# Running mysql queries onclick from index page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an index.php on my localhost and I'd like to put several buttons to run different sql queries here. The queries will be like this one :

```
  <table class="table1">
 <tr>
  <th>Date</th> 
  <th>Model</th> 
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>InProduction</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Range</th>
  <th>MaxSpeed</th>
  <th>HP</th>
  <th>Country</th>
  <th>EType</th>
  <th>Make</th>
  <th>MPG</th>
  <th>Seats</th>
 </tr>


<?php

  include ("config.php");

  $sql = "SELECT Date, Model, Type, InProduction, Price, Range, MaxSpeed, HP, Country, EType, Make, MPG, Seats FROM Auto order by Date DESC";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {


  $counter = 0;
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["Date"]."</td><td>" . $row["Model"] . "</td><td>"
            . $row["Type"]. "</td><td>". $row["InProduction"]. "</td><td>". $row["Price"].  "</td><td>".$row["Range"]. "</td><td>". $row["MaxSpeed"].
            "</td><td>". $row["HP"]."</td><td>". $row["Country"]."</td><td>". $row["Etype"]."</td><td>". $row["Make"]. "</td><td>". $row["MPG"]. 
            "</td><td>". $row["Seats"]."</td></tr>";


            $counter++;
            if($counter % 33 == 0) { ?>
                </table>

                <table class="table1">
                     <tr>
   <th>Date</th> 
  <th>Model</th> 
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>InProduction</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Range</th>
  <th>MaxSpeed</th>
  <th>HP</th>
  <th>Country</th>
  <th>EType</th>
  <th>Make</th>
  <th>MPG</th>
  <th>Seats</th>
                     </tr>
            <?php }
    }
echo "</table>";

} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>     
</table>
```

Here I included all the parameters to be displayed on the page. Instead, what I would like to do is to use different parameters in each query. So with every click of a button, I'll be able to see different parameters listed as a table on the index page. So I plan to create several php files to list different parameters, and run them with the click of a button on the index.php. How can I do this with onclick button? and is this the most suitable way for this task? Note: I will publish this only locally. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX to send a request to the server, then display the result.

Comment: Without Ajax, can it be done? because I will use it only  on the my computer/server.

Comment: you can use ajax on your local install

Comment: You can write an `onclick` function that fills in the form fields and then submits the form.

Comment: You could have a separate file for each, and add links to each page to the other pages. Not pretty though. Much better to use AJAX.

Comment: You say "parameters" but I do not see you using any parameters in your code. Typically a parameter is a value sent that affects the results.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I meant the relevant properties or characteristics recorded the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ajax solution to the problem. It is not very neat and short but it works. I am open to any shorter way to achieve this task, I'd be grateful if you share. thanks. Here is the source of the solution: http://javascript-coder.com/tutorials/re-introduction-to-ajax.phtml

So for every button, the ajax code needs to be repeated with corresponding Id's.

HTML:

```
<div id="querydiv">   </div>

<button id='actbutton1'>query1</button>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('actbutton1').onclick=function()
    {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", "query1.php", true);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)  
            {
                document.getElementById("querydiv").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, you can also just use a query string to switch on/off of what queries/data you want the user to see. You can easily add the query string to the url in a button as you wish by simply setting the parameter in the onclick event:

`<button onclick="location.url = '/mypage.php?show=firstdata';">Button1</button>`

The switch of the queries in the PHP could look like the following:

```
if($_GET['show'] == "firstdata") { 
   // 
   // the first type query here 
   // 
}elseif($_GET['show'] == "seconddata") { 
   // 
   // the second type query here 
   // 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example? pls.

Comment: I'll check it. but I plan to use several queries/buttons.

Comment: Sorry about the malfunctioned answer and comments, I am new to this..

You can use several queries/buttons as well. If you want multiple to work independent of each other, you just have to make sure that their value get passed in the query string as well, for when you click on another button.